# Powershell's blue background gone!

Tags: windows-xp, powershell

I have a new Windows XP SP3 installation and it came with Powershell freshly installed. However, when I run it, it gives me the familiar black & white `CMD` view. I really - really - prefer the default PS settings. How can I enable them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a normal function of Windows console subsystem.

Selecting properties from the system menu (right click on the title bar) to select active colours (and configure them: you can make blue output red for instance, just to confuse yourself) position, size and so forth.

This configuration is held in the shortcut so you can create a number of shortcuts with different configurations. Very helpful if you have multiple PSH sessions open.

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell, click the icon (Yes, the icon that rarely has anything useful) and click `Properties`. Select the tab `Colors` and select the colors you want. The default "blue" background is the 6th one from the left.